# How to match the height and width values in the pdf() function R to pdf resolution values?

Tags: r, pdf

I currently have a plot that I would like to save with certain resolution values. I am using the `pdf()` function in `R` with:

```
pdf("my_plot.pdf", height=5, width=10)
plot(....)
dev.off()
```

From this, I get a pdf which when I use Mac's Info in Finder, it gets:

[image]

I am wondering how I can set the `height` and `width` parameters in `pdf()` to obtain match a certain resolution above, such as 811 x 478. Thanks.

Comment: The `pdf()` commands uses inches, so you're stuck there. However, it does have the `pointsize=` argument. Ref: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If height is 811 and width is 478 pixels (although I later decided those were probably reversed) then you could divide those by a typical dpi to get a height and width in inches which is the unit that the `pdf` device expects:

```
pdf("my_plot.pdf", height=811/300, width=478/300)
  plot(....)
dev.off()
```

I'm wondering, however, whether the first number is a height or width? I suspect you may be seeing width as the first value.  Let's look at the help page:

```
?pdf
```

And look at some examples with Finder and Preview:

I'm looking at small pdf files and seeing that an icon is reported to have a resolution of 128 × 128 in Finder.app and Preview reports that it is 1.78 × 1.78 inches, so it probably was created as a 72 dpi document. The pdf() help page says that `pointsize` can be used to affect that parameter and defaults to `12` to specify 1/72 inches.

So perhaps you will want:

```
pdf("my_plot.pdf", width=811/72, height=478/72)
```